# Why doesn't CMD execute within a VBS launched from Scheduler?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

This is my VBS file contents :

```
dim com1, com2
com1 = "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -h xxx -u xxx -pxxx xxx < " & chr(34) & "D:\create_vox.sql" & chr(34) & chr(34)
com2 = "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -h xxx -u xxx -pxxx xxx < " & chr(34) & "D:\cdr_table.sql" & chr(34) & chr(34)
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run com1, 10, True
CreateObject("wscript.shell").Run com2, 10, True
```

I run it on a schedule within Task Scheduler: with SYSTEM account, highest privileges.

I tried when the script runs alone and does what it is suppose to do. But **when I run it through the scheduler**, then the above second command (com2) doesn't go through.

[EDIT4]

I've tried :

changing around the *intWindowStyle* , set it to 0, 1 and 10.

and

```
Set tempob1 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set tempob2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
tempob1.Run com1,,True
tempob2.Run com2,,True
```

and

```
Set tempob2 = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
mcom2 = "D:\importcdr.bat"
tempob2.Run mcom2,10,True
```

importcdr.bat =

```
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -h xxx -u xxx -pxxx xxx < "cdr_table.sql"
```

and

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin\mysql.exe -h xxx -u xxx -pxxx xxx < " & chr(34) & "D:\cdr_table.sql" & chr(34) & chr(34),10,True
```

and

I've split the tasks up onto two separate batch files with error logging `2>D:\sql_error.log` and ran the VBS again but no indication of an error that would provide any details on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's how I solved it :

1.) I had the original import file (CVS) and the sql file on a network share so I moved it to a local folder ; i.e : D:\folder\

2.) Within the SQL file, I changed

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\folder\DATA.CSV'`

to

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\folder\\DATA.CSV'`

I guess the Task Scheduler didn't like the path because it was on a network share and also because it didn't have the double backslashes. Once I changed this, I was able to run it without problems from the scheduler.